# What can power up an eco friendly Dino theme park?

Tags: construction, dinosaurs, power-sources

My company has just taken over the North Sentinel Island to setup a Dino attraction, construction phase is in progress and we also managed to convince the local to move and settle somewhere else (by hook and by crook) anyhow I am still looking for a power source to light up my park and obviously nuclear plant is an overkill and I don't have enough freshwater to cool the reactor. This is a multi million dollar contract to power the theme park without environmentalist showing up at my door, any taker? BTW my projected electricity consumption is around 10GWh/yr.

Comment: What are your constrain? Without stating those, the answer will just be "whatever you can use in the rest of the world"

Comment: @L.Dutch: must cost less than few million dollars, generate 10Gwh on yearly basis, not a sore thumb spoiling the scenary, eco friendly and don't produce too much heat.

Comment: sorry for the nitpicking.. eco-friendly is an empty shell.. based on personal experience, when one builds solar plants environmentalist complain that wind farm are more eco-friendly and don't spoil the scenery, and when one builds wind farms the same environmentalist complain that solar farms are more eco-friendly and don't spoil the scenery.

Comment: Some people will definitely have an answer with numbers, but IMO wind turbines placed in the sea, solar panels, or even wave farms could potentially work as potential power sources.

Comment: @L.Dutch:I see where u r coming from, currently my Dino poop farm and feral hamster wheel projects are not supplying sufficient power right now so I don't expect a perfect solution just good enough so that a couple of disappearing environmentalists are still manageable.

Comment: I think there is around zero chance they will not try to have your head for Dinos, for inhabitants, for untouched island.

Comment: @ArtemijsDanilovs: the locals are currently busy practicing their footwork on a giant hamster wheel and cannot spare the time plotting against me, we have also invited a couple of environmentalists to try and they r having lots of fun right now.

Comment: Another nit to pick: nuclear reactors can be cooled perfectly well with seawater.  Just look at how many are built on the coast.

Comment: @jamesqf: just took over the island and can't expect the local to do proper house keeping, next time I'll have velociraptors on foot patrol to deter these cunning nitpickers.

Comment: remember u can sell excess generation, you can kill two birds with one stone with tidal turbines, building them to operate at aural ranges that deter investigation by contemporary creatures/escape by any of your pets that can swim.

Comment: @GiuPiete: very good idea consider expand into an answer, as long it is not sonar whale and mosasaurus beaching is not my legal responsibility ;)

Comment: ono, answering questions is depressing, -2, -2, -2, -2, ofc, if every1 was smart enough to understand my genius answers, we wouldn't need se ;-)

Answer (score 6):

People have been studying how to provide energy to the Andaman islands, not for powering dinosaurs parks, but for powering human activities.

Based on [this study](https://www.streetdirectory.com/travel_guide/119279/science/windmill_site_selection_in_andaman_india__remote_sensing__gis.html), fossil fuels are deemed too expensive, while solar, geothermal and wind power are suitable options.

For geothermal power you would need some prospecting to investigate available hot pockets in the underground. Considering that the Andaman are volcanic islands, it is a concrete option. However, if you have to dig holes here and there it is going to be a tad intrusive on the environment. Moreover, I have no data to back up an answer, so I park this for the scope of this answer.

The cited study has found

> The wind power density observed at Andaman group of islands are within the range from 55.30 to 106.60 $W/m^2$. [...] One of the best possible sites for locating wind machines is the top of a smooth, well rounded hill with gentle slope lying on a flat plain. A site located on an island in a lake or a sea is usually an excellent site; open plain, an open shoreline as a mountain gap which produces wind funneling is good.

The study found an area where a 5 MW farm could be built, though not on North Sentinel, for obvious reasons.

> Generally the small islands situated at the leeward side of the larger islands which has an elevation greater than 60 m could not be proposed for windmills because of its elevation and canopy effects. Whereas in the case of North Passage Island it is surrounded by islands such as Baratang in East, Middle Andaman in North and Strait in South. Though it is surrounded by largest elevated islands the geographical location is well suited for windmills . Eastern side of the north passage has got a passage, Homfrey's strait. It acts as a funnel for wind flow. The surrounding elevation of this island is less than 60m and it is about 7 km away from the shore of Baratang island. Hence, this island has got an excellent geographical location for utilizing it for windmill erection.

A 1 MW turbine, about 54 meters across, working at nominal power 24/7 could theoretically produce a bit less of what you need.

Building 2 or 3 of the above mentioned turbines should provide you a large enough safety margin. However, I would also consider integrating some building with solar power and also install a fuel powered emergency generator. You don't want to run out of electricity during a typhoon, right?

Comment: geothermal is actually not that intrusive, the surface footprint is tiny, especially for one utilizing volcanics.

Comment: @John, it's the prospecting to be intrusive. And I have found no reports on it

Comment: I did the math say a reliable wind turbine which produce 10kwh cost $50000, that would cost me $50m to produce 10gwh a year!

Comment: @L.Dutch Prospecting for geothermal is not as intrusive as you think. It is however highly expensive. Unless you're exceedingly lucky, you'll need to drill multiple holes before you have enough flow at the right temperatures. Plus, you probably also need to drill suitable reinjection wells. I'd estimate you probably require 25 million just for drilling. Then, probably another 10 million to build your geothermal plant.

Comment: If you want to build on it that might be worth doing anyway, be a shame for all those expensive dinos to die fro an eruption of vent release, plus your are ging to need to do some prospective drilling just find a good water source.  since the area is seismically active MEQ (micro earthquake seismology) can be use to prospect with minimal drilling. the other upside is you can build the geothermal plant around the other facilities meaning your really are not clearing much more land than you need for the other buildings. better yet unlike the other two geothermal power is continuous.

Comment: wind and solar need a backup system because they do not produce continuously geothermal does not.

Comment: @John, if you have data to come with some calculation you can put that into an answer

Comment: @ArkensteinXII the Krafla Power Station only cost 42 million and it produces 500GWh/yr I think your estimate is way off, 10 GWh is just one or two low pressure wells.

Comment: Regarding the fuel powered emergency generator: do you think it'd be possible to use hydrogen? You could use electricity to split up the water when it's plentiful, storing hydrogen and releasing oxygen in the air; and then reversing the chemical reaction when electricity is missing. The main advantages over fossil fuel being that you would produce it locally, rather than import it, and that it's eco-friendly.

Comment: @MatthieuM., in principle that would be a possibility. However, putting close together dinosaurs and hydrogen sounds like the plot of the next blockbuster...

Comment: @John The Krafla Power Station is in Iceland, where this hypothetical Dino Park is in the middle of the Indian Ocean far away from any kind of infrastructure. The company I work for recently expanded their geothermal power plant and had to bring in an Icelandic drilling team as well as their rigs. That is what makes a powerplant on North Sentinel Island much more expensive.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII Krafla also was delayed for years due to eruptions and retrofitted twice, and is 50 times larger than what is needed with more than 30 bore holes.  if you have data to back up your estimate by all means post it.

Comment: @John I have no data that I can legally release due to it being company property.

Answer (score 6):

**Ocean Wave Energy**

They're not quite commercial yet but your throwing a couple million at a company should speed that process up.

There are several kinds, both onshore and off shore.  Some are long and thin in the water, others are like large buoys and some are on the beach.  They seem to come in a variety of nifty colors.

[image][image] 
(pictures from [BOEM](https://www.boem.gov/Ocean-Wave-Energy/))

In 2008, the [Agucadoura Wave Farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agu%C3%A7adoura_Wave_Farm) offshore in Portugal was set up and tested.  Depending on the waves at the site, each machine produces 150-750 kW.  The company had issues but some investment with a new company would make it feasible, based on what I'm reading.  (This was the kind like the left hand picture.)

**150 kW as an average output 24/7 for a year would produce 1.3 GWH.  With 8 machines, you'd get 10.4 GWH, a bit more than you need.**

I'm having trouble finding specs for how many machines will fit into what spaces, let alone costs.  But it's promising.  If you made a deal with the company to be a test site, with tourism and hosting research teams just for that (and you can provide hotels, tours, and other accommodations), you might be able to strike a pretty sweet deal.

Comment: There used to be such an experiment in France, as well, however if I remember correctly the maintenance costs were relatively high because... unexpectedly... turns out that salt water is pretty corrosive. Was the 2008 experiment more successful in that regard?

Comment: It ran for 2 months then had a technical issue. Though the issue was solved, it appears there were problems with the company that owned the tech and the project did not move forward. There are other companies but this might have been the largest test. From what I've read, and this was a search to check on tech I'd read about in the past, not something I'm expert in, the tech appears to be ready for prime time (or very close) and it's just a matter of investment. We have ocean oil drilling so there are industries used to dealing with salt water.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote as this is a solution that *could* work and is certainly a lot more realistic than a Dino Park.  So if you're already having a SciFi element, why not allow for a technology that is very close to being usable and meets all the OP's requirements?

Comment: I am not saying the problem cannot be solved; we have boats and oil rigs which are used to it. I'm just wondering what is the maintenance cost; from memory it was what did the French project in, by sapping its efficiency (cost-wise). Might still be cheaper than importing oil to a remote island though.

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes too much; unfortunately many downvoters do not leave comments, and without comments there's not much you can do to improve... I don't see anything warranting a downvote myself.

Comment: I was not able to find cost estimates in the research I did.  Not startup or maintenance.  It's a completely legit question, I just don't know.  And prototype costs are generally quite different from commercial costs anyway.

Comment: Oh sure, don't worry. I mean, it's worldbuilding, not engineering here. If the numbers or a cost comparison had been readily available it would have been nice, but there's no point sweating over it! Personally, I find the idea cool :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hydrothermal Energy**

[Hydrothermal energy](http://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/H/AE_hydrothermal_energy.html) runs of the temperature difference in a body of water. The surface water is warmer than deep water so you use a liquid with a boiling point between the two ranges to run generators.

Everything is under water so generally out of sight so no unsightly solar cells or wind turbines detracting from the animals. It doesn't require masses of construction and should be pretty storm resistant. It's 100% renewable and suitable for baseload energy. Being in a tropical area and deep water nearby, it should be pretty efficient.

Comment: The coldest water at the bottom of the sea can be 4 C. The surface is at maybe 30 C. This gives a Carnot yield of about 10%.